# Retrieving selected values of a multiselect list in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

How can I retrieve the all values selected in a multiselect list in my servlet program.I am using struts2 framework.I am able to create the multiselect list but am unable to retrieve its values in the java program.Please help.

This is my select list declaration in jsp

```
 <s:select id = "s4" label="Select the IDS to be bypassed:" name="ids" list="      {'IX','HX','LX','HD','LD','NH','LH','QL','QH','TM','SP','ALL','*'}" headerKey="0" headerValue="Select" property="selectedValues" multiple="true"/>
```

Comment: can you paste the code please

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/

Comment: What exact problem do you have? What happens when you submit your form?

Comment: I am able to retrieve the option selected when a single value is selected using ActionContext but I couldnt retrieve for multiple values

Comment: use an array of the same variable, instead of a string/integer in the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array

```
private String[] ids;
//getter & setter
```

or you can use a List

```
private List<String> ids;
//getter & setter
```